# In JavaScript DOM is it possible to clone an entire button functionality to another?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I mean is it possible to connect an existing button with a newly created button that will work as the existing button?

Reference site: https://www.ninetypercent.com/products/sleeveless-gather-maxi-dress-c5?color=red

Please paste the below code to the browser console after opening the above link:

```
let title = document.querySelector(".product-details__name").textContent;
let price;
let oldPrice = document.querySelector(".product-details__old-price");

if (oldPrice) {
    price = oldPrice.nextSibling.textContent.trim();
} else {
    price = document.querySelector(".js-product-price").textContent;
}

let div = document.createElement("div");

let path = document.querySelector("header");
div.innerHTML = `
    <div
        id="sticky-nav"
        style="position: fixed;
               top:110px;
               display: none;
               padding: 0 10px;
               justify-content: space-between;
               align-items: center;
               background-color:#e4e4e4;
               width: 100vw;"
        class="sticky-wrapper"
    >
    <div
        style="width:80%; display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items:center"
        class="sticky-text-wrapper"
    >
        <p style="margin: 0;" class="sticky-text">${title}</p>
        <p style="margin: 0;" class="sticky-price">${price}</p>
    </div>
    <span style="width: 18%; display: flex; justify-content: space-around;" class="button"></span>
</div>`;

path.appendChild(div);
const sourceElement = document.querySelector(".js-product-details-submit-wrapper button");

const destination = document.querySelector(".button");

const copy = sourceElement.cloneNode(true);
destination.appendChild(copy);

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    const scrollPos = window.scrollY;
    if (scrollPos > 1500) {
        document.getElementById("sticky-nav").style.display = "flex";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("sticky-nav").style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

I want to connect the sticky-nav button to the existing "Add to Bag" button and the functionality of both button will be the same. The same messaging as in control will appear on the PDP(Product details page) and basket icon quantity will increase. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the click-handler for the one button you could trigger the other, like so (names are made up of course):

```
stickyNavBtn.onclick = () => addToBagBtn.click();
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Andre for helping me out. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function (in JS) and call it from both the *original button (addToBagBtn in your case)* and *newly created button (stickyNavBtn in your case)*.

Like:-

```js
/*JavaScript*/

function doSomething() {
  alert("Replace with whatever task you like!");
}

var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerText = "Newly Created Button";
button.onclick = function() {
  doSomething();
}
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(button);
```

```html
<!--HTML-->

<button id="button1" onclick="doSomething()">Original Button</button>
<br><br>
<div id="container">
  <!--New button will be created here from JS-->
</div>
```